# Customizing metadata with Nuxeo 5.8 (not studio)

Tags: nuxeo

I have an instance of Nuxeo 5.8 installed and running on s3 and I want to extend it so I can add customized metadata to an asset. E.g., say a normal asset has metadata like "title", "description" and "author", I want to be able to add my own fields like "brand" and "SKU" (among others).

From what I understand it's only possible to do this via the front end when you have upgraded to Studio, so what I'm looking at doing is somehow extending the API (and the related XSDs?) to allow extra metadata. Also, once I've extended the API I'm aware that I'll have to provide my own front end that interfaces with my extended API, and will have to bypass the out-of-the-box Nuxeo front end.

What exactly do I need to do to achieve this? I'm guessing I'll need to write a Java app that interfaces with the Nuxeo API somehow?

I'm struggling a bit to find documentation for 5.8 - I did come across [Customizing metadata](http://doc.nuxeo.com/display/DAMDOC55/Metadata+Customization) for 5.5, but I'm guessing this is out of date?

Any insight would be much appreciated.

I've also posted this question on [Nuxeo's answers site here](http://answers.nuxeo.com/questions/9230/customizing-metadata-with-nuxeo-58-not-studio).

Answer (score 1):

This was answered on the [Nuxeo answers site](http://answers.nuxeo.com/questions/9230/customizing-metadata-with-nuxeo-58-not-studio).